# jQuery - don't fire 'click' on 'mousemove'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syTKq/) to demonstrate my situation.

I want to not fire the click event when the user is panning--only if it's just a simple click. I've experimented with different placements of .off() and .on() to no avail.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just set a flag when the mouse moves. Then in the `click` event handler, see whether the flag is set or not and clear it respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Waxen/syTKq/3/

Updated your fiddle to do what you want.  I put the re-binding of the event in a timeout so it wouldn't trigger immediately, and adjusted the mousemove to

Comment: perfect. Thanks! (sorry for the delay, I went on a long vacation)

Answer (score 1):

In on click event, you can detect whether mouse was pressed DOWN or UP. So let's analyse:

```
DRAG:
mouse down
mosue position changes
mouse up

CLICK:
mouse down
mouse up
```

You see - **the difference is changed mouse position**. You can **record click coordinate** in mouse down and then compare it when muse goes back up. If it is **within some treshold**, the action **was a click.**

Answer (score 0):

The only way to tell between a "click" and a "pan" would be the time the mouse has spent held down. You could create a Date in the mousedown, then another in the mouseup, and only fire your click (zoom) event if the difference between the two dates is greater than some threshold (i would guess 1/10 of a second, but you may want to experiment)

Comment: This is bad. Since you are going to interpret fast drags as clicks.

Comment: @RokKralj that is why you need to experiment and find a threshold to suit your users. When dealing with thresholds, there is never a correct answer.

Comment: But every user is different... that seems to be too limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mousemove`/`mousedown` events to set a flag that can be used in the `click` event handler to determine if the user was clicking or panning. Something like:

```
//set a flag for the click event to check
var isClick = false;

//bind to `mousedown` event to set the `isClick` flag to true
$(document).on('mousedown', function (event) {
    isClick = true;

//bind to `mousemove` event to set the `isClick` flag to false (since it's not a drag
}).on('mousemove', function () {
    isClick = false;

//bind to `click` event, check to see if the `isClick` flag is set to true, if so then this is a click, otherwise this is a drag
}).on('click', function () {
    if (isClick) {
        console.log('click');
    } else {
        console.log('drag');
    }
});​​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SU7Ef/

Answer (score 0):

I added a "panning" bool for a solution to your problem:

see http://jsfiddle.net/syTKq/4/

Basically, if the user has mousedown and mousemove, then panning is true.  once mouseup panning is false.  if just mousedown, panning is false, therefore zoom.

Comment: Your fiddle still has the problem that you are binding the `click` event handler on every `mouseup` event.

Comment: You're right, but I am merely offering a solution to the question, not fixing everything in their code logic.

Answer (score 0):

This solution solves your problem:

```
var bClicking = false,
    moved = false;;
var previousX, previousY;
var $slider = $('#slider'),
    $wrapper = $slider.find('li.wrapper'),
    $img = $slider.find('img.foo');

$img.on('click', function()
{
    if(!moved)
    {
        doZoom();
    }
});

$wrapper.mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    previousX = e.clientX;
    previousY = e.clientY;
    bClicking = true;
    moved = false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    bClicking = false;
});

$wrapper.mousemove(function(e) {
    if (bClicking)
    {
        moved = true;
        var directionX = (previousX - e.clientX) > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        var directionY = (previousY - e.clientY) > 0 ? 1 : -1;

        $(this).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft() + 10 * directionX);
        $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop() + 10 * directionY);

        previousX = e.clientX;
        previousY = e.clientY;
    }
});

function doZoom() {
    $img.animate({
        height: '+=300',
        width: '+=300'
    }, 500, function() {
        //animation complete
    });
}​
```

Basically, it calls `doZoom()` only when the mouse has not moved between the `mousedown` and the `mouseup` events.

Comment: Simple logic could be added to prevent it happening. IMO my solution is what the user expects -- a click is only a click when the mouse didn't move between the `mousedown`and the `mouseup` events.